# Unrecognized option: -Xcext.enabled=true ERROR JVM, JRuby, Scala, and RubyMine

Tags: scala, ubuntu, jvm, jruby

The error being related to something from when JRuby was installed does seam to make sense.  **When installing JRuby with RVM it had a dependency it needed to compile which I believe didn't go so well.**  Which dependency I don't quite remember.  It seams to pertain to the JVM and -Xcext.

## Scala:

```
~$ scala
Unrecognized option: -Xcext.enabled=true
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

No Google search results on this.

I have tried the latest from http://www.scala-lang.org version `2.11.1` and got this exact error.

## Java Version:

```
java version "1.7.0_55"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.4.7) (7u55-2.4.7-1ubuntu1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)
```

## JRuby:

Trying to re-install JRuby via RVM didn't ask to build any dependencies.  So I'll have to look up the `-Xcext` case online and figure it out.  ... I can't seem to find what it was that had problems.

```
~$ irb
Unrecognized option: -Xcext.enabled=true
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

And it affects RubyMine.  I really want to know where this problem has embedded itself into as it's causing quite a few headaches!

## Installing JRuby-head

```
~/.rvm$ rvm install jruby-head
Checking requirements for ubuntu.
Requirements installation successful.
$JAVA_HOME was empty, setting up JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre, if it fails try setting JAVA_HOME to something sane and try again.
Cloning from git://github.com/jruby/jruby.git, this may take a while depending on your connection.
HEAD is now at dc4248b Minor cleanup.
From git://github.com/jruby/jruby
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up-to-date.
Copying from repo to src path...
jruby-head - #mvn....................................................................................................................................
jruby-head - #installing to /home/user/.rvm/rubies/jruby-head.
jruby-head - #making binaries executable......
jruby-head - #downloading rubygems-2.2.2
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  404k  100  404k    0     0  1465k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 1470k
jruby-head - #extracting rubygems-2.2.2....
jruby-head - #removing old rubygems.........
jruby-head - #installing rubygems-2.2.2.
Error running 'env GEM_HOME=/home/user/.rvm/gems/jruby-head@global GEM_PATH= /home/user/.rvm/rubies/jruby-head/bin/ruby -d /home/user/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.2.2/setup.rb',
showing last 15 lines of /home/user/.rvm/log/1405475737_jruby-head/rubygems.install.log
[2014-07-15 22:00:00] /home/user/.rvm/rubies/jruby-head/bin/ruby
current path: /home/user/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.2.2
GEM_HOME=/home/user/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.13
PATH=/home/user/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.13/bin:/home/user/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.13@global/bin:/home/user/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.13/bin:/home/user/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/heroku/bin:.:/home/user/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/opt/RubyMine/bin
GEM_PATH=/home/user/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.13:/home/user/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.13@global
command(6): env GEM_HOME=/home/user/.rvm/gems/jruby-head@global GEM_PATH= /home/user/.rvm/rubies/jruby-head/bin/ruby -d /home/user/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.2.2/setup.rb
Unrecognized option: -Xcext.enabled=true
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
Gemset '' does not exist, 'rvm jruby-head do rvm gemset create ' first, or append '--create'.
```

Comment: That rings no bells, but on Linux, they say to download the tgz and install the latest manually.  I've never tried the packaged solutions.  (My Linux is Ubuntu.)

Comment: Every Google result for `-Xcext.enabled` has to do with JRuby, so something is really broken here.

Comment: What java version/vendor do you have? What scala version are you trying to use? How do you install it?

Comment: I would download the tgz, Scala 2.9 is quite outdated by now. Try 2.11.1.

Comment: What do you have, if anything, in `$JAVA_OPTS`, `$_JAVA_OPTIONS`, and `$JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you have `-Xcext.enabled=true` in one of the JVM's options environment variables, such as `JAVA_OPTS`, `_JAVA_OPTIONS`, or `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS`. I assume at some point it was supposed to be added to a JRuby-specific environment variable but accidentally got put in one of those JVM ones.

Comment: Thanks! Unsetting `$JAVA_OPTS` worked per terminal session. I achieved that with `export JAVA_OPTS=` or `unset JAVA_OPTS`. But the problem was in `/etc/environment` it had the line `JAVA_OPTS="-Xcext.enabled=true"`. After removing that and rebooting the computer the problem has been solved!

Comment: Thanks for the bounty! I'm not sure how it might have gotten into /etc/environment.